# Does domain pointer overrule .htaccess redirect from country tld to .eu tld or is there workaround?

Tags: .htaccess, 301-redirect

I've been trying to redirect with a .htaccess file but its not working. Now I think I know why, just need a second opinion.

I have domain pointers set from a .nl domain and a .lv domain to point to my .eu domain. So far so good, only I believe that because of this the .htaccess file is not working.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.lv [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ example.eu/lv$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any thoughts for a solution?

So to clarify; at first support gave me the following code to use:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mediagreenhouse\.lv [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mediagreenhouse.eu/lv$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

This did not work. I looked into more options and tried the first posted option, deleted all server files, re-uploaded everything, cleared browser(s) cache(s) and reloaded. Nothing seems to work.

So I guess the first question to answer is:

> Is the domain pointer overruling the apache coding (do I say that right), so is a .htaccess redirect impossible in this setup?

Comment: well, it doesn't work at all... the server just does the pointer redirect. So whenever you type in the .lv domain, it just redirects to the main .eu domain. The support from my hosting told me to use a htaccess redirect but all versions I tried so far don't seem to work. The redirect keeps going to the .eu index instead of the .eu/lv/ folder

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache? What is the actual domain name?

Comment: yes i did clear the cache, and just again; no result. Site is mediagreenhouse.lv

Comment: Hmm. Do you have _another_ rewrite somewhere else in your configuration?

Comment: no, i knew ofr sure but checked again, and; no

Comment: What does your rewrite log say?

Comment: What do you mean by "domain pointer"? This redirect obviously came from Apache, so that is where you need to be looking.

Comment: I have been trying to find the _rewrite log_ but must admit that this goes beyond my knowledge, I cannot find it. 

With the _domain pointer_ I mean that in the direct admin I choose one main domain. Other related domains are directed to the nameservers and in the advanced features in direct admin I set them as domain pointers.

Comment: Can you post your httpd.conf? Specifically any section that defines the "AllowOverride" parameter.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it so far, it's just that I am completely in the dark when it comes to this stuff. I tried to find how to grab that httpd.conf file but when it states i need to _'run this or that in Apache'_ I just don't know how to do it. Maybe conclusion is I'm in over my head and need to get some more programming skills or seek professional help. I just love to be able to crack it myself (with all the help of people from here of course).